# odoo website withought login download product attachment showing error

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-website

odoo website withought login download product attachment showing error 
 "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Same code for downloading product level attachment working well if your logged in. But not working for without login. Attached all screen shoot please check. 
Without Login: [Without Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCngU.png)

While clicking on Catalogue it will open in another window and showing:[After Clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3PfL.png)

Comment: I don't see any programming issues here, so the odoo help forum would be the right address for this question.

Answer (score 0):

IN the controller of odoo we can make the authorization to 'public', 'user', 'None'.
you should check your controller eg:

```
@http.route('/path', csrf=False, type="http", methods=['POST', 'GET'], auth="public", website=True)
```